# Alternative to Couchbase Single Server For GeoCouch integration

Tags: couchdb, geospatial, couchbase

Couchbase announced changes to CouchDB distribution:

http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-2011-year-review

CouchBase Single server has GeoCouch integration, is there an alternative to get GeoCouch support on CouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Couchbase for it. You can use GeoCouch with Apache CouchDB. It currently does on; work with CouchDB 1.1.x, but I'll update it to work with 1.2.x as well.

Comment: Are there plans to merge Geocouch with CouchDB?

Comment: Long term goal for me is to keep GeoCouch seperate from CouchDB, but I'd like to see it as a sub-project in the far future.

Comment: We have a client who we had convinced to run on Couchbase single server - with their demise we need to move them onto CDB 1.2. However they are using spatial so we have to build them a custom version - and for Windows that means using CygWin and there are compile issues with GeoCouch there...Bottom line, I would NEVER have pushed a client onto such an unstable platform had I known I would end up in this situation. I just want a stable downloadable windows exe with included spatial queries...

Answer (score 0):

There is the refuge project, which is open source, has spatial search (fork of geocouch), based on CouchDB trunk, and maintained by one of the CouchDB contributors.

http://refuge.io/

https://github.com/refuge/refuge

Currently there is no 'binary' release, but I have found it very easy to build.

Hope that helps.